# Bash Shell Script: Read folders date modified and list them out by month

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I want to be able to read a bunch of folders in a folder and list them out monthly starting with the most recent/current month (12mos) and be seperated by a horizontal ruler in the browser.? Thanks!

```
for directory in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -print | egrep -v "^\.$")
 do
    date_file=$(date -r $directory +"%B")
    echo '<div class="month_txt">'$date_file'</div>' >>  $FILE
    echo '<hr />' >>  $FILE
    echo '<div class="folder">'$directory'</div>' >>  $FILE 
done
```

**READ:**

FOLDER_A
FOLDER_B
FOLDER_C
FOLDER_D
FOLDER_E

**OUTPUT:**

---

AUGUST:
FOLDER_A
FOLDER_C

---

SEPTEMBER:
FOLDER_D

---

DECEMBER:
FOLDER_E

---

JANUARY:
FOLDER_B

Comment: By "starting with the most recent/current month", do you want to sort the list in chronological (from oldest to latest) order, or vice versa?  Your expected output looks like sorting from the past to the future, which is unlikely with timestamps.

Comment: top of the page will have the newest and the bottom of the page will contain the oldest. :p.

Comment: Then if we include the years in the list, it should be:  
  `Aug 18, Sep 17, Dec 16, Jan 16`  
in order, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your requirement correctly, how about:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE="./test.html"

declare -A ym2mo    # map "1809" to "September"
declare -A dirlist  # list of dirname for each yymm
declare -a ymlist   # list of yymm like "1809" ...

while read -r yymm month dir; do
    if [ -z "${ym2mo[$yymm]}" ]; then
        ym2mo[$yymm]="$month"
        ymlist+=("$yymm")
        dirlist[$yymm]="$dir"
    else
        dirlist[$yymm]+=" $dir"
    fi
done < <(
# a process substitution to generate a list of dirs and sort them
# as newest in top and oldest in bottom.
# Then the result is fed to the while loop above.
for dir in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec basename {} \; | egrep -v "^\.$"); do
    month=$(date -r $dir +%B)
    yymm=$(date -r $dir +%y%m)
    echo "$yymm" "$month" "$dir"
done | sort -r -k1)

# finally generate the html fragment
for yymm in ${ymlist[@]}; do
    cat << EOS >> "$FILE"
    <div class="month_txt">"${ym2mo[$yymm]}"</div>
    <hr />
    <div class="folder">"${dirlist[$yymm]}"</div>
EOS
done
```

**Explanation:**

The key issue would be how we can sort the list with month in (reverse) chronological order. I've introduced a temporary field `yymm` which holds year and month in each two digits as "1809" for "Sep 2018" so we can sort the list by using it as a key.

Another trick is a process substitution to suppress creating a temporary file just to sort the list.

Hope this helps.

In case `declare -A` doesn't work due to bash version, here is an alternative with AWK:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE="./test.html"

for dir in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec basename {} \; | egrep -v "^\.$"); do
    month=$(date -r $dir +%B)
    yymm=$(date -r $dir +%y%m)
    echo "$yymm" "$month" "$dir"
done | sort -r -k1 | awk '{
    # gather the list
    if ($1 in ym2mo) {
        dirlist[$1] = dirlist[$1] " " $3
    } else {
        ym2mo[$1] = $2
        dirlist[$1] = $3
        ymlist = ymlist " " $1
    }
}
END {
    # format and print the result
    len = split(ymlist, ary)
    for (i = 1; i <= len; i++) {
        yymm = ary[i]
        print "<div class=\"month_txt\">" ym2mo[yymm] "</div>"
        print "<hr />"
        print "<div class=\"folder\">" dirlist[yymm] "</div>"
    }
}' >> $FILE
```

The code below demonstrates how you can pass the shell variable values to the AWK script:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE="./test.html"
hrefpath="/path/to/the/href"
newdir="mynewdir"

for dir in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec basename {} \; | egrep -v "^\.$"); do
    month=$(date -r $dir +%B)
    yymm=$(date -r $dir +%y%m)
    echo "$yymm" "$month" "$dir"
done | sort -r -k1 | awk -v param1="$hrefpath" -v param2="$newdir" '{
    # see the line above how you can pass shell variable values to AWK.
    # you can refer to param1 and param2 in the lines below.
    # add "-v var=val" pairs if you need more.
    if ($1 in ym2mo) {
        dirlist[$1] = dirlist[$1] " " $3
    } else {
        ym2mo[$1] = $2
        dirlist[$1] = $3
        ymlist = ymlist " " $1
    }
}
END {
    len = split(ymlist, ary)
    for (i = 1; i <= len; i++) {
        yymm = ary[i]
        print "<div class=\"month_txt\">" ym2mo[yymm] "</div>"
        print "<hr />"
        print "<div class=\"folder\">" dirlist[yymm] "</div>"
        print "<a href=\"" param1 "\"><img src=\"" param2 "/thumb.jpg\" height=\"250\" width=\"300\"/></a>"
    }
}' >> $FILE
```

Finally here's the pure bash version without an associative array:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE="./test.html"

print_html() {
    cat << EOS >> "$3"
    <div class="month_txt">"$1"</div>
    <hr />
    <div class="folder">"$2"</div>
EOS
}

while read -r p1 p2 p3; do
    if [ -z "$prev_p1" ]; then              # 1st line
        month="$p2"
        dir="$p3"
    elif [ "$p1" = "$prev_p1" ]; then       # same month as prev line
        dir="$dir $p3"
    else
        print_html "$month" "$dir" "$FILE"
        month="$p2"
        dir="$p3"
    fi
    prev_p1="$p1"                   # keep yymm value for next

done < <(
for dir in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec basename {} \; | egrep -v "^\.$"); do
    month=$(date -r $dir +%B)
    yymm=$(date -r $dir +%y%m)
    echo "$yymm" "$month" "$dir"
done | sort -r -k1
)
print_html "$month" "$dir" "$FILE"  # flush the last line
```

Comment: thanks! this is really neat! I tried running the script and its having a problem with declare -A command it saying its an invalid option I'm using automator with run shell script /bin/bash not sure if thats an issue or not. it seems its been giving mixed results using shell script inside automator with some code. any ideas? Thanks again! I'm really excited to learn from this.

Comment: @Likenota `declare -A` makes the variable an associative array which was introduced from bash 4.2. I suppose your bash version may be older than that. (You can check the verion number with `bash --version`)
As an alternative, I've rewritten the second half of the script with AWK, which will be hopefully available on your platform.
If it still has a problem, please let me know.

Comment: that works great! i just dont quite understand your way of writting the bottom half. if i wanted to use variables with the print how would i do that? im trying to incorporate a way to include a thumb.jpg with the folder .. like this?  echo '<img src="'$newdir'/thumb.jpg" height="250" width="300"/></a> </div>' >> $FILE

Comment: @Likenota The bottom half is written in AWK scripting language and it may be difficult to modify the code without knowing AWK. If you are interested, I'd encourage you to learn AWK. It is a simple language and will be easy for one who has a background of bash like you.
Going back to your question, if you want to pass a value of a bash variable to the AWK script, take a look of my last post as a reference. I'm afraid I can not fully answer your question without knowing the total structure (how to obtain the newdir path name, etc.) but it will be a starting point for you.

Comment: @Likenota Sorry for the frequent modifications but I've posted the no AWK, no associative array version. Hope it helps.

Comment: no its perfect!! you are extremely helpful thank you!!! last one works really well! it.It seems to not want to condense two folders if they have the same month however and it creates another section. still tinkering but any ideas?

Comment: @Likenota I've intended so the code merges folders in the same section if they were last modified in the same month, same year. Try to add a debugging line `echo $p1 $p2 $p3` next to the line `while read -r p1 p2 p3; do` in my script and examine the output.
The 1st field ($p1) contains the yymm data like "1809" and adjacent lines which have the same yymm data are supposed to be merged. If it doesn't solve the problem, could you post the output so I can get the clue? BR

Comment: the folders have other content and folders in it.. i think that might have something to do with it. the output is 1809 September Assets 1809 September 300x250 1809 September 160x600 ... etc.  I just need the top folders modified date not anything under it.

Comment: it gives me a merged result when i put this print_html "$month" "$dir" "yo" "$FILE"but then remove the previous month lol. I'm suspect in believing that the problem is in the very last For dir in command?..

Comment: Hmm.. I'm afraid I can't reproduce your problem in my environment. Regarding the directory layers, the `-maxdepth 1` option in the `find` command should work to find only in the top directory. What about the result if you execute `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec basename {} \; | egrep -v "^\.$"` on the command line in the directory?

Comment: i guess im trying to figure out what the flush the last line does because it seems the months arent grouping together. example i want to add the following instead of div class month  echo '<a href="'$newdir'/preview.html" target="_blank"><img src="'$newdir'/thumb.jpg" height="250" width="300"/></a> </div>' >> $SHOW

Comment: "Flush the last line" works this way: Intead of using associative arrays, I've modified the code to use a one-length fifo. When the new line is fed, the yymm field is compared with `prev_pl`. If it matches, it means the line is in the same month and dir is merged to the previous one. If it doesn't, previous data are printed out. When the final line is processed, the last line remains
in the fifo and it must be explicitly flushed. Is that clear?
Anyway I'd like you to make sure my last code (__without adding your modifications__) works in your enviromment. It's working in my tests so far.